# Proof of Axiom of Transparency in Aumman's model of knowledge

Tags: game-theory

Could someone provide a proof of the axiom of transparency for Aumman's knowledge model taking as primitive the information function? I do know how to do the inverse inclusion but not the following:

$K(E)\subseteq K(K(E))$

Comment: I have added what I think you mean by "inclusion sign".  If that was incorrect, feel free to edit as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much @EricWofsey, it was indeed what I meant.